# How do I efficiently run a PHP script that doesn't take forever to execute in wamp enviornemnt...?

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a script that pretty much loads a huge array of objects from a mysql database, and then loads a huge (but smaller) list of objects from the same mysql database.

I want to iterate over each list to check for irregular behaviour, using PHP. BUT everytime I run the script it takes forever to execute (so far I haven't seen it complete). Is there any optimizations I can make so it doesn't take this long to execute...? There's roughly 64150 entries in the first list, and about 1748 entries in the second list.

This is what the code generally looks like in pseudo code.

```
// an array of size 64000 containing objects in the form of {"id": 1, "unique_id": "kqiweyu21a)_"}
$items_list = [];

// an array of size 5000 containing objects in the form of {"inventory: "a long string that might have the unique_id", "name": "SomeName", id": 1};
$user_list = [];
```

Up until this point the results are instant... But when I do this it takes forever to execute, seems like it never ends...

```
foreach($items_list as $item)
{
    foreach($user_list as $user)
    {
        if(strpos($user["inventory"], $item["unique_id"]) !== false)
        {
            echo("Found a version of the item");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the echo should rarely happen.... The issue isn't with MySQL as the $items_list and $user_list array populate almost instantly.. It only starts to take forever when I try to iterate over the lists...

Comment: `Is there any optimizations I can make so it doesn't take this long to execute?` - Yes! Use JOINed database queries to check for that regular behaviour; don't load large volumes of data into PHP and then iterate over those nested arrays

Comment: Index your arrays with the ID of each as the *key*, then you can perform fast lookups by array key instead of looping 320 million times *at your current database size*

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here :-(

Comment: Joins are not possible in this case, and index the arrays does nothing to help me find my result Robbie... I NEED to iterate over all records not select records...

There's definitely something wrong because the script has been running for 10 mins now without finishing or printing out anything....

Comment: Can you point out the source of your problem? is that the query that is long? Or the php loops/process?

Comment: @olibiaz the php loops/process.... As soon as I throw in the if(strpos($character["inventory"], $item["unique_id"]) !== false) if statement it takes forever, if the loop does nothing... it's relatively fast.

Comment: Do you think that improve your db model in order to allow you to join an user and an item could be a good things to do?

Comment: @Ricky have you tried reducing the array to 1000 in the first and 1000 in the second to see if that script finishes?

Comment: @dchayka it completes, but is really slow for the amount of iterations happening...

Comment: What time does it take for one outer loop iteration, roughly?

Comment: You can try using XDebug and EXPLAIN statements in MySQL to see what's taking up time

Comment: Are the `unique_id` sequential numbers? Would a search like this yield a flash positive? `strpos('1,29,45', '2')`

Comment: **EVERY** performance optimisation **MUST** start with profiling. Otherwise you all are just making educating assumptions (which often are wrong)

Comment: There is nothing wrong. 10^8 calls to strpos() on "a long string" is expected to take forever on a home computer. Echo something inside the loop (outside of the `if`) if you are worried your script stalled. As it has already been suggested, this problem could be computed in a few miliseconds at the database level.

Answer (score 0):

With 130M iterations, adding a break will help somehow despite it rarely happens...

```
foreach($items_list as $item)
{
    foreach($user_list as $user)
    {
        if(strpos($user["inventory"], $item["unique_id"])){
            echo("Found a version of the item");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

alternate solutions 1 with PHP 5.6: You could also use PTHREADS and split your big array in chunks to pool them into threads... with break, this will certainly improve it.

alternate solutions 2: use PHP7, the performances improvements regarding arrays manipulations and loop is BIG.

Also try to sort you arrays before the loop. depends on what you are looking at but very oftenly, sorting arrays before will limit a much as possible the loop time if the condition is found.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is almost impossible to reproduce. You need to provide an example that can be replicated ie the two loops as given if only accessing an array will complete extremely quickly ie 1 - 2 seconds. This means that either the string your searching is kilobytes or larger (not provided in question) or something else is happening ie a database access or something like that while the loops are running.

Answer (score 0):

You can let SQL do the searching for you. Since you don't share the columns you need I'll only pull the ones I see.

```
SELECT i.unique_id, u.inventory
FROM items i, users u
WHERE LOCATE(i.unique_id, u inventory)
```